# laravel - how to create custom message bag, errors array

Tags: laravel

i am trying to make custom message bag but unable to make, i want to use the $errors

```
$errorMsgs = [];
    if (Model::where('name', '=', Input::get('name'))->exists()) {
       $errorMsgs['company_name'] = 'name already exists';

    }else if (Model::where('age', '=', Input::get('age'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_phone'] = 'age no already exists';

    }else if (Model::where('mobile', '=', Input::get('mobile'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_mobile'] = 'mobile already exists';

    }else if (Model::where('pri_email', '=', Input::get('primary_email'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_email'] = 'Primary email already exists';

    }else{
// success 


        }
```

Actually i want to use errors foreach

```
 @if ($errors->any())
               <div class="alert alert-danger">
                   <ul>
                       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                           <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                       @endforeach
                   </ul>
               </div>
           @endif
```

Comment: `\Session::flash('errors', $array)` should cover it, no? however I'd suggest using a validator instead - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation, they're for that purpose and very simple to implement

Comment: i am not doing form validation i am checking duplicate entry, if any duplicate entry found then errors should return in message bag

Comment: Validator has a `unique` property for that purpose https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique

Comment: you are not getting, please read the question again i want to create message bag for errors then i will echo using foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see from your question why the out-the-box [unique Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) is not being used, it's for seemingly exactly this purpose. Anyway, the gist of the manual way would be something like...

```
// Controller
public function WhatEverController()
{
    $data = [];

    $errorMsgs = [];
    if (Model::where('name', '=', Input::get('name'))->exists()) {
       $errorMsgs['company_name'] = 'name already exists';

    }
    if (Model::where('age', '=', Input::get('age'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_phone'] = 'age no already exists';

    }
    if (Model::where('mobile', '=', Input::get('mobile'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_mobile'] = 'mobile already exists';

    }
    if (Model::where('pri_email', '=', Input::get('primary_email'))->exists()) {
        $errorMsgs['primary_email'] = 'Primary email already exists';
    }

    if(count($errorMsgs)) {
        return  redirect()->back()->withErrors($errorMsgs);
    }

    return view('someview');
}


// Blade
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

One more detail, with your `if/elseif` use, it will always stop going through on the first match therefore always a maximum of one `$errorMsg`. I have changed it to a number of `if` statements as this will provide the opportunity to obtain an array of errors.

Comment: i tried your code and it throw error ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function any() on array (View: /var/www/html/cb/resources/views/frontend/company/user/index.blade.php)

Comment: okay you have done great you are very near i need the same thing but when we have errors in array i want to echo them but using the php html which i post above

Comment: how can i  done this with laravel validation you have mentioned above

Comment: Amended the controller return, please retry

Comment: you made my day :)

Comment: Can you explain it please

Comment: Awesome! `return  redirect()->back()->withErrors($errorMsgs);` -> the `withErrors()` method updates the `$errors` bag that's available to every view with content specific to this controller. `redirect()->back()` just boots you to your last route. You may want to consider adding `withInput()` - `return  redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($errorMsgs);` to preserve the input data (better UX).